# Appcelerator show an image

Tags: android, image, titanium, appcelerator

Greetings,

I'm trying to simply display an image using Appcelerator on Android.

I don't understand why it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
var back=Titanium.UI.createImageView({
 url:'images/back.png'
});

win.add(back);
```

I've also tried putting the image inside a view:

```
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
   borderRadius:10,
   backgroundColor:'red',
   left:10,
     right:10
});
var back=Titanium.UI.createImageView({
 url:'images/back.png'
});
view.add(back);
win.add(view);
```

I'm totally stuck and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: did you try reaching out to in their forums?

Comment: Yes, but I find there's much better traffic on stackoverflow.

Comment: Better interface, too. Appcelerator's forums are pretty useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working as follows:

```
var back_fn=Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'images/back.png');
var back=Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image:back_fn,
    top:10,
    right:10
});
win.add(back);
```

Thanks for all the responses guys,

Comment: you shouldn't have to  do it with the file system, but I  am glad it works

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var back=Titanium.UI.createImageView({
  url:'images/back.png',
  height : 130,
  width : 130
});
```